# What should I use instead of deprecated Tree widget in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, tree, gxt, checkboxtree

I am developing a GWT app, where I should use checkbox tree. But every tutorial that i found is using widget.core.client.tree.Tree widget which has an option .setCheckable() which give as tree like checkbox. But that widget is deprecated. What else I should use to make check box tree in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

For GWT the http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.html replaced the normal tree.

But it is maybe better to look into alternative UI widget sets instead of the default widgets and build your UI with one of these.

For example :
Bootstrap : https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/
Material  : http://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/